# how to get rows data on the column side

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a employee table with salary according to number of years as follows:

```
Employee_table
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
emp_ID -  FirstName- LstName   salary  ...    year -  
001   -   xx     -     yy   -   03212         2000       
001   -   xx     -     yy   -   04212         2001        
002   -   xxx     -    yyy  -   03425         2000         
002   -   xxx     -    yyy  -   04425         2001          
003   -   xxxx    -    yyyy  -  03429         2000         
003   -   xxxx   -     yyyy  -  04429         2001         
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And I want to write a query which will give me the employee data with year on the column side as:

```
tblResults
---------------------------------------------------------------------
emp_ID   2000       2001          ....     ....            
---------------------------------------------------------------------
01        03212     04212   
02        03425   - 04425    
03        03429     04429
```

Comment: I feel a pivot in your future.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, as @SpectralGhost said, you can use a `PIVOT`. If you know beforehand how many years you need, then you can do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT emp_ID, salary, [year]
        FROM Employee_Table) AS ET
PIVOT(MIN(salary) FOR [year] IN ([2000],[2001],[2002])) AS PT
```

If you don't know how many years there are, then you are gonna need dynamic sql (so first, go to [this link](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)). Then try this:

```
DECLARE @Years NVARCHAR(MAX), @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Years = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME([year]) 
                        FROM Employee_Table
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

SET @Query = '
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT emp_ID, salary, [year]
        FROM Employee_Table) AS ET
PIVOT(MIN(salary) FOR [year] IN ('+@Years+')) AS PT'

EXEC(@Query)
```